# Javascript / Jquery HubSpot Sortable, Sortable.init() sortable not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, hubspot

So I'm dynamically creating some div tags and updating them over time, I need to get a sortable to work so I can sort divs by their various fields. I downloaded the HubSport Sortable script and followed their example, and I tried it both with Sortable.init(); and without putting that before the rest of the code and it just says its not defined but it is loading the js file which doesn't make sense to me.

Link to the API
http://github.hubspot.com/sortable/api/options/

```
console ReferenceError: Sortable is not defined vmstatus:50
```

Code:

```
    <link rel="icon" href={% static 'customers/favicon.ico' %}>
    <link href="{% static 'css/loading.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/dashboard.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="http://dygraphs.com/1.0.1/dygraph-combined.js"></script>    
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'sortable.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "/vmstatus/", 
                        type : "POST",
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data : {
                            selected_customer : $("#selected_customer").val(),
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                            },
                            success : function(json) {
                                $('#table-repeat-data').remove();
                                setInterval(update, 5000);  
                                var on = '<img src={% static "icons/on2.jpg" %}>'
                                var off = '<img src={% static "icons/off.jpg" %}>'
                                $('#table_name').append("<table class='table' id='table-repeat-data'><thead><tr><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''> <b>VM Name</b></th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''><b>PowerState </b> </th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='N'><b>Commands </b></th></tr></thead><tbody>");

                                for (var index = 0; index < json.vmlist.length; index++) {
                                    if(json.vmlist[index][1] == 'poweredOn'){
                                        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr><td id="' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '">' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td id="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '1">' + on + '</td><td id="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '</td></tr>');
                                    }else{
                                        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr><td id="' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '">' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td id="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '1">' + off + '</td><td id="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '</td></tr>');
                                    }
                                }
                                Sortable.init(); //line 50 is here
                                var dataTable;
                                dataTable = document.querySelector('#table-repeat-data');
                                Sortable.initTable(dataTable);

                            },
                            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                            }
                    });
                    return false;
            });
        });
function update(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "/vmstatus/", 
                        type : "POST",
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data : {
                            selected_customer : $("#selected_customer").val(),
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                            },
                            success : function(json) {
                                var on = '<img src={% static "icons/on2.jpg" %}>'
                                var off = '<img src={% static "icons/off.jpg" %}>'
                                for (var index = 0; index < json.vmlist.length; index++) {
                                    if(json.vmlist[index][1] == 'poweredOn'){           
                                        var get_element_id = json.vmlist[index][2] + '1';
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][0]).innerHTML = json.vmlist[index][0];
                                        document.getElementById(get_element_id).innerHTML = on;
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][2]).innerHTML = json.vmlist[index][2];
                                    }else{
                                        var get_element_id = json.vmlist[index][2] + '1';                                   
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][0]).innerHTML = json.vmlist[index][0];
                                        document.getElementById(get_element_id).innerHTML = off;
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][2]).innerHTML = json.vmlist[index][2];
                                    }
                                }

                            },
                            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                console.log('Bad');
                                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                            }
                    });

}        

</script>
```